# Querying works on shell but not on the Django program code

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-cms

I'm a complete novice to python and Django.

I have tried several solutions I found on stack overflow, but I still get the same issue. I've tried querying from shell and it works well, but not on my code.

I've installed `pylint` using

```
pip install pylint-django
```

I have also changed the **Linter settings** on **Settings > User Settings > Python** from `pyLint` to `pylint_django` and also to `flake8`, but no positive results.
I still get the message "Class Courses has no 'objects' member pylint(no-member)"

These are my codes from models.py:

```
class Courses(models.Model):
course_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
course_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='course_images/')
course_duration = models.TimeField() 

 def __str__(self):
 return self.course_title
```

The views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Courses

def homepage(request):
    cos = Courses.objects.all()
    context={ 'courses': cos }

    return render(request, "main/home.html", context)
```

I need help. I'm completely stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was right under my nose the whole time.

Goto **settings > Search for "terminal" > open any of the do `"Edit in settings.json"`** and add the code below.

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugins=pylint_django"]
```

**NOTE:** *make sure you add a comma at the end of the last line before adding the code below, else you'd get an error.*

Save that and then go back to settings and search for `"lint"` check the **left hand side** of the search and locate `Python Configuration`

Make sure **"The Linter to use"** is set either to `pyLint` or `pylint_django`

That should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

That is an error message from the linter, not from library. You need not worry about that. Since the IDE might have default linter settings applied, that might be a cause for this. Also, you can keep singular name for your models as a practice and if you register that model in admin, it automatically gives a `s` in the end.

It should like this

```
from django.db impot models

class Courses(models.Model):
    course_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    course_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='course_images/')
    course_duration = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.course_title
```